# Does InMemory store in CoreData not support indexing?

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data, xctest, in-memory

TLDR;
**Could any one please explain if its correct to assume indexes don't play a part in fetch requests, when store of InMemory type is used?**

I have a Data Model with multiple Entities and each of them have indexes to speed up search. I have a very large dataset for testing purpose.

My tests, I thought, were slow due to using a store of sqlite type. All the tests executed in say 'x' time interval when store of sqlite type was used.

So I changed the store type to InMemory, assuming it would speed up the tests. To my surprise the tests were now taking more time. All the tests executed in say 'y' time interval when store of in memory type was used.

Store Type: SQLITE ----> Time taken for tests 'x'.

Store Type: InMemory ----> Time taken for tests 'y'.

Observations: 'y' was always significantly less then 'x'(almost 2 seconds of difference in my case)

I was surprised and gave a thought over why it was so. I could only think of indexes not being used in case of InMemory store, slowing down the tests compared to when the store was of type SQLite.

Comment: Any reproduction path?

Comment: @J.Doe You can add an enity with two or three attributes and add an index to it in a data model. I have a very large data set and I cant share it due to obligations. If you try with SQLITE store type you will find the fetches faster compared to fetching from InMemory store type. In paticular I run tests which access the data set frequently and my tests are faster with the SQLITE store(2 seconds faster).

Comment: Offtopic but do you have a solution for https://stackoverflow.com/q/58584486/7715250? When you create the in-memory container, can you preload a sqlite file?